# "Did you check if […]"

Tags: grammaticality

Is this a grammatically correct/formal way to ask the question of this type? Here is an example

> Hey, did you check if the payment went through?

What's the better way to rephrase it?

Comment: Related: [When are “if” and “whether” equivalent?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/9520/when-are-if-and-whether-equivalent)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think yours works. This might sound nicer:

> Hey, did you check whether the payment went through?

Comment: +1: Thanks, I considered using "whether" instead "if." In fact, it is a good follow-up question to identify the different between if and whether

Comment: Some will say that "whether" is the more or only correct choice in this sentence.  But in practice you wouldn't use "hey" and "whether" in the same sentence.

Comment: "Have you checked" is very much more natural to my (British) ears than "Did you check". But I don't think that's true in North American.

Comment: @Peter: Sup G, yo lissn up, y'all know whether dat payment went thru? =P.

Answer (score 0):

Please, make sure your payment went through before [whatever].

Comment: That's a decent alternative. however, you changing the meaning, shifting it from the question to a direct statement form

Comment: True and I'm sorry. I didn't notice you specifically asked for a question. Maybe "Did you make sure you payment went through?" is a viable solution?

Comment: I would remove the comma after "Please" ("Please make sure..."). Other languages seem to like the comma in that place, and I've seen it from a lot of non-native speakers, but in my experience native speakers will only add the comma if there's a strong need to separate the two parts of the sentence ("Please, <pause> don't do that again").

Answer (score 0):

Consider:   Did you check "whether" the payment went through?  "If" not, you should check as soon as possible.  This demonstrates the use of "if" and "whether" in the context.