# To determine if or to determine whether?

Tags: word-choice, if-whether

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [When are “if” and “whether” equivalent?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/9520/when-are-if-and-whether-equivalent)

Do these two have the same meaning:

1. To determine **if** something is correct.
2. To determine **whether** something is correct.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

In familiar conversation, your two examples have the same meaning, but it's a better idea, in my opinion, to use 'whether' when you're introducing two possibilities like this, because it avoids potential ambiguity.  For example, the following sentence is ambiguous *if* people use 'if' as a substitute for 'whether' :-).

> Tell John if the car breaks down.

That ought to mean that somebody is only to tell John anything *on the condition that* the car breaks down.  If you want to indicate that somebody is to tell John either way, you could use:

> Tell John whether the car breaks down.

Answer (score 9):

The short answer is that they do mean the same thing. The long answer is that it depends how they occur in a particular context. In (2), *whether* implies *or not*. *If* does not necessarily do so in (1). The difference is perhaps clearer in the sentence *Let me know if you’re coming*.  That has two possible meanings. It could mean *let me know **only if** you’re coming*. It could also mean *let me know if you’re coming, and also let me know if you’re not coming*. If the second of those is intended, then the use of *whether* removes any possible ambiguity.