# What does "Let me know if the problem persists" exactly mean?

Tags: ambiguity

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [When are “if” and “whether” equivalent?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/9520/when-are-if-and-whether-equivalent)

Which one is the correct meaning of *"Let me know if the problem persists."*? Or is it ambiguous?

1. If the problem persists, let me know.
2. Let me know whether the problem persists or not.

Comment: "Let me know if the problem persists" sounds to me like it means "if the problem persists, let me know". Option 2 sounds like you are putting words in the speaker's mouth.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Ambiguous**.

In informal writing, "if" and "whether" are used interchangeably.[¹](http://grammar.quickanddirtytips.com/if-versus-whether.aspx) This is not recommended because it creates ambiguity, but it is an unfortunate fact. Consequently, the statement can mean either:

> Let me know **whether** the problem persists.

or:

> Let me know **(only) if** the problem persists.

Answer (score 3):

A logician might say that the person being addressed need say anything only if the problem did persist. In practice, the context will usually make it clear what is required.