# IF or WHETHER? - that's the question

Tags: if-whether

I'm a native German speaker, so forgive me if I use wrong words or wrong syntax.

In a major news outlet today I read this headline:

> Time to decide if we want UN focused & effective or on the sidelines

I wonder whether this should be:

> Time to decide **whether** we want UN focused & effective or on the
>   sidelines

I am often confused where **if** or **whether** is appropriate to use.

Comment: And for the above phrase?

Comment: @user111530, your examples seem exactly the same in meaning and acceptability, to me.

Comment: Either works in this case.

Comment: [The answer by Neil Coffey](http://english.stackexchange.com/a/15388/15299) in that possible duplicate noted above is a very good summary.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Although both work, in my mind,  *whether* expresses a choice between two (or more) alternatives, while *if...or* puts a bit more emphasis/preference on the first alternative. In this case, the speaker seems to favor a "focused & effective" UN.

Answer (score 0):

Whenever two alternatives are presented or there is an implicit binary choice, I prefer 'whether' to 'if'.
 [Grammar Girl agrees:](http://www.quickanddirtytips.com/education/grammar/if-versus-whether)

> Although in informal writing and speech the two words are often used interchangeably, in formal writing, such as in technical writing at work, it's a good idea to make a distinction between them because the meaning can sometimes be different depending on which word you use. The formal rule is to use if when you have a conditional sentence and whether when you are showing that two alternatives are possible.

Comment: Would you mind quoting, in your answer, the relevant parts of that Grammar Girl post?