# Is this sentence grammatically correct / does it make sense?

Tags: grammar

I just don't know anymore. I've been trying to figure this one out for about an hour now. Is this sentence right?

> Inquiries as to if compensation payments or replacements of the phones
>   will happen were ignored.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [When are "if" and "whether" equivalent?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/9520/when-are-if-and-whether-equivalent)

Comment: Possibly @EdwinAshworth. However, the question wasn't actually if *if* and *whether* could be set equal.

Comment: No, the question is a proofreading question. If you could actually refine what the real underlying problem is, it would be Edwin's suggestion.

Comment: Given that the accepted answer was to replace *if* with *whether*, it's kind of obvious that this is a duplicate of the other mentioned question.

Comment: The sentence is fine as is, but the real question is, why would you spend an hour scratching your head about it (and risk that every reader would have to do the same) if in just ten seconds you could have reworded it in ten different ways that are clearer.

Comment: I... don't know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd write it as:

> Inquiries as to **whether** compensation payments or replacements of the phones will happen were ignored.

As it is, it sounds awkward.

[Google ngrams tends to agree.](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=as%20to%20if%2Cas%20to%20whether&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cas%20to%20if%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cas%20to%20whether%3B%2Cc0)

Comment: Thanks. In sentences as... "complicated" as this one, is it always possible to replace **if** with **whether**?

Comment: @DeBedenHasen - Sometimes the whether is iffy.

Comment: @DeBedenHasen I'm not sure it's a global rule, but it seems to work for sentences like "I'm not sure if you're going." -> "I'm not sure whether you're going."

Comment: @HotLicks  Does that mean if is sometimes whethery? :-)

Comment: Alright. Thanks for the clarification. And thanks @PeterK. for ngrams. - **EDIT:** Will accept your answer in 3 minutes. Damn timeout...