# Ask her if she will go with us OR Ask her whether she will go with us (?)

Tags: grammar

Which one sounds better?

> (A) Ask her if she will go with us

OR

> (B) Ask her whether she will go with us (or not)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [When are "if" and "whether" equivalent?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/9520/when-are-if-and-whether-equivalent). I'll risk saying that though the option with 'whether' is grammatically safer, the use of 'if' in its place here has grown so much that it's got to be considered acceptable in informal spoken contexts.

Comment: Looks like the answers to (A) can be "yes" or "no", while the answers to (B) include "No, she will go with her sister."  
The if is "binary" whether the "whether" seems open to many options.